# How to update "slave" content pages using updatepanel?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages, scriptmanager

I am creating an asp website using a Master page. I have some links inside the content page. I want to surf them using updatepanel, leaving the master page content intact. How do I achieve that?

Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="TestJquery.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            this is master
        <% Response.Write(DateTime.Now); %>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestJquery._default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    This is slave
    <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="default2.aspx" runat="server">default.aspx</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Content>
```

Default1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestJquery.default2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    this is slave
    <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="default.aspx" runat="server">default</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You can use the iframe, not the UpdatePanel for that work. The updatepanel is for other jobs, not the one you looking for.

Comment: So how can I ask the server to render an aspx page for me?

Comment: Its main pointless, one page have a lot more elements (than the html), images, media, etc, if this page is not on your server you need to make a full proxy, if its is, then change your way of thinking to solve what ever you try to solve.